# Google Cloud Identity Platform password policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, passwords, google-identity

In Google Cloud Identity Platform is there a password strength policy for the user/pass provider?
We need a way to set the password complexity for public users.

I've added the user password provider but haven't seen any controls for password.

Comment: Which product are you using (Free, Premium, G Suite)? What do you mean by `user/pass provider`? Items like password policies are well documented by the vendors. What research have you completed? Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We are using Premium. I mean the Email/Password identity provider. It's a built in provider like SAML.
This is different from G Suite account authentication. We are using Identity Platform to authenticate external users for our application.

Comment: Since you have not specified the Identity Provider (IDP), we cannot answer your question. I suggest that you update your question with details and also read their documentation. When you integrate an IDP, the IDP handles authentication (user/password/MFA/token/API-KEY/etc.). You define the password policies at the IDP.

Comment: My question was not about SAML, I used that as an example for other built in providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the password pattern in Cloud Identity Platform. You have to code it if you want one.

However, I strongly recommend you to activate the MFA before spending time in password complexity rules.

Comment: That is conclusion I've come to and it's a bit disappointing for an authentication service.