# Firebase Identity Platform - setting password policy in from non-JS (Python or UI) environment?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth in my project.
I need to set the complexity of the password users choose.

I found the following link which explains how to do this using Firebase JavaScript Admin SDK but I don't know JS. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/password-policy
How can I set up password policy using other means?

This answer says it is not possible but documentation says otherwise. [Google Cloud Identity Platform password policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588626/google-cloud-identity-platform-password-policy)

Or JS admin SDK is the only way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the Node.js SDK is the only way to set the password policy, so you'll have to figure out how to run the script from the documentation you linked.

I recall that work was being done to allow setting this policy from the Firebase console too, so you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to cast your vote for that.

---

**Update** Mar 26, 11:30am (pacific): There **is** an `updateConfig` REST API that you can call from any language to change the password policy of your project. See https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig.